# C# Entity Framework : custom field translation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table which contains data like this:

| ID | Text1 | Number1 | Text2 | Text3 | Decimal1 | Text4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 23 | Doe | London | 3.4 | UK |

There is also another table which translates the column names of the data table above to their user defined names:

| ID | LogicalName | UserDefinedName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Text1 | Firstname |
| 2 | Number1 | Age |
| 3 | Text2 | Lastname |
| 4 | Text3 | City |
| 5 | Decimal1 | Score |
| 6 | Text4 | Country |

The schema is given and cannot be changed. The problem I'm facing is that `data.Text1` is not always the firstname, it can be anything depending on the translation table.

So I need a query like this:

```
Data data = context.Data.Where(d => d.Firstname == "John").ToList()
```

To be interpreted like

```
Data data = context.Data.Where(d => d.Text1 == "John").ToList()
```

I'm thinking of a translation function which is queried by Linq to get the actual column name instead of just using the one specified in the query. Is this possible? Otherwise I guess I need to use raw queries which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Can you show the expected raw SQL query?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? User defined strings only make sense when displaying data, not when querying the database or writing the query. All UI stacks have  way to localize labels, columns etc. There's no "translation" concept in SQL, the language, though. You can alias columns and expressions with `AS` but the name has to be defined in the query itself. Tables and columns are like types and properties in C# - they must be known in advance

Comment: I'm thinking of an abstraction on the code side. The sql query should be in any case `SELECT * FROM data WHERE Text1 = "John"` . The point is that I can't hardcode `.Where(d => d.Text1 == "John")` because, depending on the actual database instance, Text1 _can_ be the Firstname, but may also be something totally different. So I need an abstraction layer to Linq that looks up the logical name to use in the data table via the user defined name from the translation table.

Comment: If the column names are different between instances, you have different database schemas, and I would be concerned how you got to that point, and if there are any other differences between the schemas. You might be able to use the same data classes, but different contexts, and specify the column names when creating the model, assuming a EF-core style ModelBuilder.

Comment: I don't think EF Core can do this... Maybe you can declare a view in the database and map the entity to the view.

Comment: You are totally right, this schema is a mess - but it is a third party design and I need to use it without being able to change it. I found this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32968/QueryMap-Custom-Translation-of-LINQ-Expressions and searched further about the MapToExpression Attribute, but either the article from 2012 is outdated or I got the idea wrong.